# SoX batch file... encoding in u-law 8000 kHz

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, sox

I am trying to make a batch file for SoX, and I have the standard command line code working...

```
sox.exe -V test-input-file.wav -e u-law -r 8000 -c 1 test-output-file.wav
```

Here is the batch file I have created...

```
cd %~dp0
mkdir converted
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox %%A "converted/%%~nxA" -e u-law -r 8000 -c 1
pause
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: @foxidrive the error is sox FAIL sox: missing filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your initial batch command worked, see if this changes anything:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
mkdir converted 2>nul
FOR %%A IN (*.wav) DO sox.exe -V "%%A" -e u-law -r 8000 -c 1 "converted\%%~nxA"
pause
```

Comment: Note the change I made to support long filename elements - two double quotes around the second `"%%A"`